# Help setting up PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having trouble getting PHP's SimpleXML to work with our [XML feed](http://events.stanford.edu/xml/mobile.xml). I'm just calling the title attribute for simplification. When I run any of this code it only exports empty h3 tags. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I've tried this:

```
        <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://events.stanford.edu/xml/mobile.xml');

        foreach($xml as $event){
            echo '<h3>', $event['title'], '</h3>';
        }

        ?>
```

...and this:

```
        <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://events.stanford.edu/xml/mobile.xml');

        foreach($xml->Event as $event){
            echo '<h3>', $event['title'], '</h3>';
        }

        ?>
```

...and this:

```
        <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://events.stanford.edu/xml/mobile.xml');

        foreach($xml as $node){
            echo '<h3>', $node['title'], '</h3>';
        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://events.stanford.edu/xml/mobile.xml');

    foreach($xml->Event as $event){
        echo '<h3>', $event->title, '</h3>';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: And to clarify.. array access [ and ] is for attributes, property access (->) is for elements. Title is an element, not a property.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the object `$event` as an array, which does not work, either do as the other answers say and reference it as an object (`$event->title`) or convert it to an array (cast? `((array)$event)['title']`. I'd suggest the first.

I sense that you're used to javascript objects which can be indexed as hash tables, whereas in PHP arrays are completely different to objects.